# Pandas- Multiple left-joins only returns latest left-join in the output table

Tags: python, pandas

When I try to join multipe df's only the latest join appears in the output table.

```
merged_df = df.merge(df_2, how = 'left', left_on = 'customer_id', right_on= 'customerid' )
merged_df = merged_df.merge(df_3, how = 'left', left_on = 'customer_id', right_on= 'customer__id' )

merged_df
```

When I run the code above I get the following output (this only returns results of the join from df_3 instead also incl. df_2.):

```
customer_id  customer__id  device
5729         5729          mobile
4924         4924          mobile
9315         9315          desktop
```

Expected output df

```
customer_id  customerid  country   customer__id   device
5729         5729        US         5729          mobile
4924         4924        CA         4924          mobile
9315         9315        CA         9315          desktop
```

**Output samples:**

df

```
customer_id  
5729
4924
9315
```

df_2

```
customerid  country
5729         US
4924         CA
9315         CA
```

df_3

```
customer__id  device
5729         mobile
4924         mobile
9315         desktop
```

Comment: works fine for me, you must have made a mistake with the names

Comment: strange! it doesn't work for me. But thx for checking